# HTML 5 API: Can I check if my csv file has certain columns before uploading it?

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I am making a webpage that uploads csv files to the server using the HTML5 file upload API. But before I upload I would like to verify if the csv contains certain columns. E.g. I require a column called "id" and if that column doesn't exist I do no want to upload it.

Currently I am waiting for the file to be completely uploaded to the server, and check the file server-side. I wonder if there is a way to do this with JavaScript client side?

I need this because the files are often very large and I don't want to wait until the files is completely upload and then find out something was wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a .csv file that is local to my system in a HTML5 document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938992/how-to-parse-a-csv-file-that-is-local-to-my-system-in-a-html5-document)

Answer (score 2):

If your page/app only runs on [a subset of browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi), you can use the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) to read the first part of the file (client-side) and determine if it has the necessary information.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is similar to [How to parse a .csv file that is local to my system in a HTML5 document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938992/how-to-parse-a-csv-file-that-is-local-to-my-system-in-a-html5-document).

You can do your test on the .csv files locally with the JS [FileAPI](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/). But you need to consider that HTML5 is a *draft* at this time and *not* a general implemented standard.

**Further reading** on parsing .csv files with JavaScript can be found here:

- [Javascript code to parse CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data)
- [Example HTML5 csv parser on github](https://github.com/RohitRox/js_csv/blob/master/index.html)